# Is it possible to customize Apple iOS TouchID AlertView

Tags: ios, mobile

Apple provides a standard AlertView for TouchID local authentication, which consists of a fingerprint image, enter password, and cancel. Is it possible to use a custom screen instead?

I read through the documents and seem not be able to find a way.

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  You can change the text of the prompt to indicate why you are requesting TouchID but that is all.

Answer (score 2):

I don't konw how to customize it, but maybe you can do some configuration on it.

such as you can set `localizedFallbackTitle` to an empty string and so on.